# Puppet, hiera and erb - erb would not recognize array

Tags: puppet, template, hiera

I have a pretty annoying error I am desperate to fix. I have a puppet module where certain things are kept in a yaml file (hiera) so that people could quickly edit just that part.

The structure is nested.

The template like this:

```
<%= @platforms[@platform]['users_allowed'][@host].class %>
```

renders to this:

```
Array
```

But when I try to iterate over it:

```
<% @platforms[@platform]['users_allowed'][@host].each do | pubkey | %>
<%= pubkey %>
<% end %>
```

puppet says:

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Failed to parse template somemodule/templates/authorized_keys.erb:
Filepath: /etc/puppet/modules/somemodule/templates/authorized_keys.erb
Line: 1
Detail: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

How does it suddenly become nil and how do I iterate here?

I'm afraid I'm stuck here and not even sure in which direction I should search for solution.

Rewriting module without hiera or without nested structure is not an option in this one case.

Comment: what version of puppet?

Comment: It's 3.3.1. I belive the part of the problem is this (quoting puppetlabs docs): The lookup functions and the automatic parameter lookup always return the values of top-level keys in your Hiera data — they cannot descend into deeply nested data structures and return only a portion of them. To do this, you need to first store the whole structure as a variable, then index into the structure from your Puppet code or template. -- but it's still weird to me. It does see the type and it can render a template with the whole array but it can't index.

Answer (score 2):

I've tested on my puppet and the correct syntax that worked was:

```
<% @platforms[@platform]['users_allowed'][@host].each do | pubkey | -%>
  <%= pubkey %>
<% end -%>
```

I hope I helped.

Comment: What version of puppet do you run? I think omitting one pipe must not help and if it does I'm in trouble. I mean, in Ruby array.each do | i | is valid, so it should be valid in erb, too.

Comment: When I typed I forgot to type a |. I already fix. Sorry for the mistake. Answering your question: Puppet 3.4.3.
I used as the documentation recommends:
http://docs.puppetlabs.com/learning/templates.html